# Firestore Transaction for Multiple Documents from Array of Keys

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore documentation states that it is possible to carry out any number of get operations followed by any number of set/update/delete operations using a transaction. I would like to know how one would do this by feeding in an array of DocumentKeys. The data structure is:

```
Products --> DocumentKey_1 --> Number: 43 
             DocumentKey_2 --> Number: 82
             DocumentKey_3 --> Number: 23
             DocumentKey_n --> Number: m
```

Consider the situation where I have an array containing any number of random DocumentKeys from 1 to n. How do I construct a single atomic transaction in Swift using these DocumentKeys, where the 'Number' property of each document is decremented by 1? I have considered using a for loop, though I am sure that this would just generate a series of non-atomic operations.

Comment: Javascript would utilize a `promise.all` on an array of `.get()`'s. I believe there is a promise plug-in for Swift.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have an array called keys:

```
var keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
keys = keys.map({ $0 - 1 })
// should change keys to [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I'm not near a compiler to test this but this code should do the trick

Comment: Hi @Jake, unfortunately the answer you have provided is not the answer I am looking for, as the question is in the context of Firestore, not swift alone.